# Microsoft SQL Server local report culture is not supported: 3072 is invalide culture identifer

Tags: ssms, windows-10

I am using Windows 10, language Serbian, SQL Management Studio 2016 and can't use Database reports because there is error:

> An error occurred during local report processing  Culture is not
>   supported  Parameter name: culture 3072 (0x0c00) is invalid culture
>   identifier.

I try with different settings for Windows 10 - language (English), try with different settings for SSMS (English) but got same error.

Do you have idea how to solve this?

P.S. My Windows 10 system locale settings:

```
Get-WinSystemLocale
LCID       Name            DisplayName
----       ----            ----
9242       sr-Latin-RS     Serbian(Latin, Serbia)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think 3072 (0x0c00) is an invalid locale ID, at least according to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc233965.aspx). So this looks like a corrupted Windows installation, perhaps from a flaky disk (eg. a byte overwrite of a locale 0x0c1a, which is the code for "Serbia and Montenegro (Former)").

You can try changing the current locale from Control Panel.

Comment: Today there was automatic big windows update on my computer and problem was solved! Thank you @RemusRusanu, it was probably corrupted windows installation.

Answer (score 23):

Had the same error.

Turns out that it was my setting in Region -> Formats -> Format. When it was on English (World) or English (Europe), I would get this error. Setting it to English (United States) solves it.

I'm guessing that English (World) or English (Europe) were new formats with Windows 10, and SSMS is not prepared for it.

Comment: FRENCH Switzerland culture blocked import of a flat data file. Setting English US and worked like a charm. Thanks.

Comment: cool direction otherwise i was trying lot of other trick but only this language format to English (United States) works for me

Comment: Some problem here. With English (Belgium) it failed, with Dutch (Belgium) it worked fine...

Comment: Solved my problem, thanks!

Comment: Solved my problem also, thanks!

Comment: I was searching where to find the place to configure the "region" in SSMS. I did not find it there but in the Windows region setting.

Answer (score 0):

No need to change the RegEdit Register Editor.

If you are facing the `Error 0xc002f210: Preparation SQL Task 1: Executing the query "Culture is not supported. Parameter name: culture 3072 (0x0c00) is an invalid culture identifier."` just set the Regional format to English (United States):

[image]

This also works if you are trying to import a flat file to Azure SQL Database